# Can a non-rooted phone android user see/edit the data stored in Realm DB?

Tags: android, realm, rooted-device

I am storing my data in `Realm DB`, I wanted to know is it possible for a `non-rooted` phone user to `see/edit` this data or not ??

I am asking this as a security point of concern because when using `Shared pref/SQLite` on a `non-rooted` phone no one can `see/edit` the data.

Comment: There's a variety of ways they can do it, including rooting.  If you're worried about keeping data hidden from the user of the phone, don't persist it on the client at all.

Comment: I have to persist otherwise why would I use a DB. Also i just want to keep away `non-rooted` phone users atleast.

Comment: If you put any data on a device you don't have physical control over, consider it compromised by the owner of that hardware.  Anything else is asking for trouble.  An easy way to get around this is to install the app on an  SD card and read the sd card in a PC.  Or run it on an emulator, emulators are pre-rooted.

Comment: @GabeSechan yeah thanks i know, i just wanted to know whether for non-rooted phone does realm protect itself or not ?? Rooted phone i know a user can get access to any storage files in android whether it is SQLite/Shared pref.

Comment: And I'm saying you're worried about something that isn't worth worrying about.  You're adding a speed bump that can be worked around by anyone but the most technically illiterate.  If you have data you can't let them access, then don't store it on their phone.  By the way, Room IS SQLite.  Its a library on top of it, the underlying data store is just a SQLite db.

Comment: Room ?? anyway, you are right just wanted to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user will be able to view the database depends on where you have saved the database. If you are not modifying the location of the database, then by default the realm database is stored at the same location as SQLite db. So, the user should not be able to view the file.

However, if you are placing the database in a custom folder accessible without root (like sdcard) the user will be able to view it.

For the safety purpose, you can encrypt the database. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@strv/encrypted-realm-android-keystore-d4f0915905e9)

Comment: I am using default config with encryption enabled. So it will be open/edit by `non-rooted` user or not ??

Comment: non-rooted users should not be able to view that since the DB file is stored in /data/data/<package name>/files/<database name>.realm which is not accessible by non-rooted users.